# PHP email function works only with my PC

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

I've got a problem with a PHP script which has the aim of send an email.
I get the data from each field with jQuery, put the data in a variable called "content" and send it via AJAX to my script (email.php).
The problem is that I receive the email, but only me!! If somebody else from another pc try to fill the form and then send the email this script won't work.

Here is my JS code who send the data to my script:

```
if (send) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://www.domain.com/email.php',
                    data: content           
                });
}
```

and here's my email.php script:

```
<?php 

    // Getting the vars from the form
    $nome_corso             = $_POST['nome_corso'];
    $data_corso             = $_POST['data_corso'];
    $nominativo             = $_POST['nominativo'];
    $data_nascita           = $_POST['data_nascita'];
    $luogo_nascita          = $_POST['luogo_nascita'];
    $cittadinanza           = $_POST['cittadinanza'];
    $codice_fiscale         = $_POST['codice_fiscale'];
    $titolo_studio          = $_POST['titolo_studio'];
    $residenza              = $_POST['residenza'];
    $tipo_contratto         = $_POST['tipo_contratto'];
    $anno_assunzione        = $_POST['anno_assunzione'];
    $qualifica_aziendale    = $_POST['qualifica_aziendale'];
    $az_priv                = $_POST['az_priv'];
    $email_partecipante     = $_POST['email_partecipante'];
    $ragione_sociale        = $_POST['ragione_sociale'];
    $sede_operativa         = $_POST['sede_operativa'];
    $sede_legale            = $_POST['sede_legale'];
    $telefono_azienda       = $_POST['telefono_azienda'];
    $fax_azienda            = $_POST['fax_azienda'];
    $email_azienda          = $_POST['email_azienda'];
    $partita_iva            = $_POST['partita_iva'];
    $codice_fiscale_azienda = $_POST['codice_fiscale_azienda'];
    $ente_bilaterale_bool   = $_POST['ente_bilaterale_bool'];
    $ente_bilaterale_text   = $_POST['ente_bilaterale_text'];
    $auth_bkr               = $_POST['auth_bkr'];

    $content = "Nuova iscrizione al corso: \r\n" . "\r\n" .
                $nome_corso . 
                "\r\n" . 
                $data_corso .
                "\r\n" . "\r\n" .
               "DATI PARTECIPANTE: \r\n".
               " \r\n NOMINATIVO: "                         . $nominativo . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n DATA DI NASCITA: "                    . $data_nascita . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n LUOGO DI NASCITA: "                   . $luogo_nascita . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n CITTADINANZA: "                       . $cittadinanza . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n CODICE FISCALE: "                     . $codice_fiscale . "\r\n" . 
               " \r\n TITOLO DI STUDIO: "                   . $titolo_studio . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n RESIDENZA: "                          . $residenza . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n TIPOLOGIA DI CONTRATTO: "             . $tipo_contratto . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n ANNO ASSUNZIONE: "                    . $anno_assunzione . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n QUALIFICA AZIENDALE: "                . $qualifica_aziendale . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n AZIENDA\PRIVATO: "                    . $az_priv . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n EMAIL PARTECIPANTE: "                 . $email_partecipante . "\r\n" . 
               " \r\n RAGIONE SOCIALE: "                    . $ragione_sociale . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n SEDE OPERATIVA: "                     . $sede_operativa . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n SEDE LEGALE: "                        . $sede_legale . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n TELEFONO AZIENDA: "                   . $telefono_azienda . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n FAX AZIENDA: "                        . $fax_azienda . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n EMAIL AZIENDA: "                      . $email_azienda . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n PARTITA IVA: "                        . $partita_iva . "\r\n" . 
               " \r\n CODICE FISCALE AZIENDA: "             . $codice_fiscale_azienda . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n AZIENDA ADERENTE AD ENTI BILATERALI: ". $ente_bilaterale_bool . "\r\n" .
               " \r\n LISTA ENTI BILATERALI: "              . $ente_bilaterale_text. "\r\n" .
               " \r\n IL PARTECIPANTE HA SCELTO L'OPZIONE: ". $auth_bkr;

    // Email to admin
    mail("info@mydomain.com" , "ISCRIZIONE CORSO" , $content, 'From:  service@mydomain.com ','-f  service@mydomain.com ');

    // Email to user
    mail( $email_partecipante , "ISCRIZIONE CORSO" , $content, 'From:  service@mydomain.com ','-f  service@mydomain.com ');

?>
```

Comment: you dont seem to have any email headers.. Also is the form input for `email_partecipante` correct ?

Comment: Have you tried not using a var for //email to user ($email_partecipante) and using instead a prefixed mail? just for test?

Comment: All the data are corrects. If I fill this form from my pc, my client receive the email. If my client try to compile the form and send the email from his pc, this isn't working.

Comment: @MarcoMura No, I haven't. Everything works fine from my pc, from any other pc this script isn't working

Comment: 1) Try to test that. 2) If email.php is on the same server try not to use an absolute path for Ajax call, maybe it's that.

Comment: The email.php script is on the same folder of the JS script which makes the AJAX call @MarcoMura

Comment: Tryed to change the ajax url? solved anything? How is the Enviroment different? Which difference are between your local machine and your server?

Comment: In any case, if you or another user from another country try to use this code, he will always use the server, which is located in the same place. So it should have the same behaviour for every users. Now, maybe your client is typing a wrong email, because I don't see any tests or regex for checking the user typed a correct email. It may be a good idea to add this, if you will sell this solution to a client !

Comment: I'm working on Wordpress on a hosted server. Changing the url of the ajax call changed anything.